# Fetch JSON Twitter search data with WinJS

Tags: javascript, json, windows, xmlhttprequest, winjs

Trying to authenticate to receive search data feed from Twitter in a Windows 8 app. This is straight from a text book written when Twitter didn't require authentication so it should work although I've added user and password without any results (worse, the app terminates).

JS:

```
        args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll().then(function () {

            WinJS.xhr({
                url: "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=windows8",
                //type: "GET",
                user: "myusername",
                password: "mypassword"
            }).then(
            function (result) {
                var jsonData = JSON.parse(result.responseText);
                //create a binding list object from the json
                var bindingList = new WinJS.Binding.List(jsonData.results);
                //get the list view element from the DOM
                var listView = document.getElementById("sampleListView").winControl;
                //bind the data sources
                listView.itemDataSource = bindingList.dataSource
            });
        }));
```

HTML:

```
<div id="sampleListView" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks - changed it to https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=windows8 which makes the app terminate less quickly now but still no results...

Comment: Did you read the response from that URL? `{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}`

Comment: Can't see the error in Visual Studio 2013 anywhere (although I'm still learning the app-side-of-things). Certainly not it the JS console or on-page. It terminates in the terminateAppHandler in base.js

Comment: You're getting an error from the XHR request, add a second function to your `then()` call and you can capture the error

Comment: As @jakerella mentioned it, you're missing the error hanlder function. Take a look at this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh700337.aspx